# How can you assign a color to a cell if it's value matches the value of a cell in a different sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The reason I ask this question is so it is visually easier to glance and see what the schedule is looking like instead of having to read all the values.

Say I have a [Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkpu9.png) sheet that contains my schedule where each row (excluding the header) is a different time slot and can have one person of a number of people assigned to it. I want it to then be colored depending on the color of the cell with the matching value in a [separate sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8ojH.png). I would manually add/remove people from this second sheet as well as make sure their cells are colored, but I don't want to add/remove another thing of conditional formatting every time if I can avoid it. At the moment, adding/removing the conditional formatting is my solution.

Is this even possible? I want to add as many people as necessary to the list and it could be changing constantly but don't want to add and remove the conditional formatting for each one every time there's a change.

I made a test spreadsheet if anyone wants to see if they can tackle it there: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hJpBIqU-vFVJFPit8FNR-X6G-Ra3ehILCySVm8fs-lk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as there isn't an easy way of doing this with built-in functions or formulas, I wrote a small script that should work. If you check the [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hJpBIqU-vFVJFPit8FNR-X6G-Ra3ehILCySVm8fs-lk/edit?usp=sharing) you'll see when you edit the values in the B column on the "Schedule" sheet to one of the workers' names after a short delay it will change the color. For that I'm using this script:

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

const onEdit = () => {
  setWorkerColor("B2:B","A1:A");
}

const setWorkerColor = (rangeToColor,workerList) => {
  let sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // ss.getSheets()[0] here means the left most sheet, change according to your needs
  let cell = sheet.getRange(rangeToColor);
  
  let rowCount = cell.getHeight();
  let workerValues = cell.getValues();

  // ss.getSheets()[1] means the second left-most sheet, a.k.a "Workers" sheet
  let listOfWorkers = ss.getSheets()[1].getRange(workerList).getValues().filter(worker => { 
    return worker != "" // removes all blank cells from the preset list of workers
  });
  let listOfWorkersColors = ss.getSheets()[1].getRange(workerList).getBackgrounds().filter(worker => { 
    return worker != "#ffffff" // removes all the white colored cells from the list of colors
  });
  
  let workerColorValues = new Array(workerValues);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    workerColorValues[i] = new Array(0); // necessary as the array has to be 2D even if it's only one column
    if (workerValues[i] != "") {
      let foundMatch = false;
      for (let j = 0; j < listOfWorkers.length; j++) {
        if (workerValues[i][0] === listOfWorkers[j][0]) {
          workerColorValues[i][0] = listOfWorkersColors[j][0];
          foundMatch = true;
          break; // Only need to find the first match, once it's found we can exit this loop
        }
      }
      if (foundMatch === false) {
        workerColorValues[i][0] = "#ffffff";
      }
    } else {
      workerColorValues[i][0] = "#ffffff";
    }
  }
  cell.setBackgrounds(workerColorValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible without a script that would read the background color of a cell.

if the script is not an option you can still do it but every name needs to have own conditional formatting:

[image]

```
=$B2=INDIRECT("Workers!A1") 

=$B2=INDIRECT("Workers!A2")

=$B2=INDIRECT("Workers!A3")

=$B2=INDIRECT("Workers!A4")
```

Comment: Those conditional formatting rules are my current solution but it's a bit monotonous. A script is an option but I'm not sure how to even get around to doing something like this.